# Overriding NameValueCollection ToString

Tags: c#, overriding, namevaluecollection

I have Written the following extension method to override the `NameValueCollection.ToString`:

```
public static string ToString(this NameValueCollection a)
{
    return string.Join("&", a.AllKeys.Select(k => $"{k}={a[k]}"));
}
```

But it still uses the default `ToString` method.

When I add the `override` keyword I get an error:

> 'ToString(NameValueCollection)': no suitable method found to override

And when I add `new` keyword it says that `new` keyword is not needed:

> 'ToString(NameValueCollection)' does not hide an inherited member. The new keyword is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to override ToString() for `NameValueCollection`, you need to create a new Object which inherits  `NameValueCollection`

```
public class CustomNameValueCollection:NameValueCollection
{
     public override String ToString()
     {
         return string.Join("&", AllKeys.Select(k => $"{k}={this[k]}"));
     }
}
```

You fill your collection in your new CustomValueCollection and you can call ToString().

```
CustomValueCollection coll = new CustomValueCollection();
coll.Add("key", "value");

string collString = coll.ToString();
```

Comment: Well I was hoping to change the default tostring method, but this seems to be the only way to go. Thanks a lot.